# How to set default value for label expression in Jenkins project configure page

Tags: jenkins

currently I got a request that I need to block all build jobs in Jenkins master, every jobs must be built in slaves.

So I would like to configure every new job in Jenkins will be default checked in "Restricted where this project can run", and then a default value for Label Expression, e.g. "docker-slave". So that everytime dev create a new job, they don't have to choose which jenkins slave will be used (actually they don't want to do it).

[I would like this to be default for every new job <-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D17Pp.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you could go to `/computer/(master)/configure` and set "# of executors" to 0.

Comment: Hi, thanks @burnettk, and yes, I already set master executors to 0, and then all the new jobs are pending as our dev does not check "Restrict where this project can run" in their job configure. As we use ECS to load our jenkins slave and it's must be used with "Restrict where this project can run", otherwise It will not load itself. That's why I'm looking for a way to set default value to Label Expression in every jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways:

- Under the master node configuration, you can specify to exclusively run jobs that are bound to the master. If none is bound, none is run. This means, the one writing jobs has to explicitly bind the job to master.
- There is a [job restrictions](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Job+Restrictions+Plugin) plugin that allows finer control over what can run on each node. You could allow to run jobs on master only from a specific user.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan Hanke, job restrictions can only restrict but give no warning when dev create job so all the jobs will be pending :(.

Comment: somehow I need a way to add default value to Label expression as well as default checked in "Restrict where this project can run", OR prevent them create the job if they don't use "Restrict where this project can run". otherwise when blocking build on master, all the job pending and dev all come to me and ask why it didn't run :(

Comment: I use ECS plugin to create jenkins slave, so no physical node other than master node.